# Sitecore 8: Automatically fill a placeholder by a default rendering

Tags: sitecore, rendering, sitecore8, contentplaceholder, experience-editor

I was playing around with dynamic placeholders and was struck by a prefilling concept.Is there a way to select a default rendering for one of my placeholders which would avoid the "select rendering" dialog in experience editor ??

Scenario: I have a rendeing called "PageHead" which has three renderings. One of them is a placeholder "PageTeaserPh" which currently allows two renderings: one is "PageTeaser" and second "PageTeaserWithImage". I want the placeholder "PageTeaserPh" to always have the rendering selected as "PageTeaser" and therefore avoid the dialog "Select rendering" .

I did some homework and was wondering if this is something related to **Standard values** (we can have it at template level; not sure for renderings though) and also i have heard of **command template** concept (not in-depth).

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have renderings assigned on standard values of templates, each new item would then have your **PageTeaser** rendering.

If you wanted to automate this process have a look at the `<mvc.getXmlBasedLayoutDefinition>` pipeline, we are injected common renderings by extending this pipeline.

**Updated**

I've found some code samples and blog posts that should help point you in the right direction for manipulating the layout details.

```cs
public void AddSublayoutToItem(string itemId, string sublayoutId)
{
    using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
    {
        if (Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(itemId) && Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(sublayoutId))
        {
            //Get the master database and get the item on which you want to add sublayout
            Database masterDatabase = Database.GetDatabase("master");
            Item item = masterDatabase.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));

            //  Or you can also get Sitecore Item from Context Database as per your requirement
            //  Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));

            if (item != null)
            {
                // Get the layout definitions and the device definition
                LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
                LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
                DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

                //Create a RenderingDefinition and add the reference of sublayout or rendering
                RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition = new RenderingDefinition();
                renderingDefinition.ItemID = sublayoutId;
                //Set placeholder where the rendering should be displayed
                renderingDefinition.Placeholder = "content"; 
                // Set the datasource of sublayout, if any
                renderingDefinition.Datasource = "{24240FF2-B4AA-4EB2-B0A4-63E027934C38}";

                // you can also set datasource of sublayout using Sitecore Path
                // renderingDefinition.Datasource = "/sitecore/content/Home/Books";

                //Add the RenderingReference to the DeviceDefinition
                deviceDefinition.AddRendering(renderingDefinition);

                // Save the layout changes
                item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml(); ;
                item.Editing.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from here - http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/06/how-to-add-sublayout-to-sitecore-item.html

Also a couple of other blogs on the topic

Comment: All i have is a pageteaserPh placeholder and a pagehead sublayout. Not sure how to implement what you say ?